# devise+omniauth_facebook how to get a large facebook picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using devise_omniauth facebook to retrieve the users picture from facebook, all works fine, I just want to get a bigger picture, I already read many similar questions, but they all provide URLs which I find not convenient. 
Here is my user.rb :

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.name = auth.info.name
        user.image_string = auth.info.image
        end
    end
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the default size for image in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` as,

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :image_size => 'large'
end
```

just to mention, facebook provides 4 sizes of images `small, square, large, normal`

If you are using devise, check in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
 Devise.setup do |config|
...
  config.omniauth :facebook,  ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :image_size => 'large'
...
end
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I had accepted this answer long time ago!! I don't know why it didn't show as accepted.